# Library/Compiler to use continuations in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, continuations

I am looking for a JavaScript library/compiler that allows developers to use continuations like found in Scheme (or Rhino). For example, this library should allow us to do some similar to:

```
var kont;
function add(x,y) {
  return x +
        (function() {kont = new Continuation(); return y;})();
}

var executed = false;  //avoiding infinite recursion
show(add(5,1));        //show 6

if (!executed) {
  executed = true; 
  kont(20); // show 25 because the "y" binding is changed
}  

var result = cont(20);
```

The main points behind this code are: a) to capture and b) resume the control flow (or execution) of a JavaScript script. In order to resume the execution, I suppose the "capture" should be a first-class value like 'kont = new Continuation()'

I searched for libraries, but I only found jwacs (http://chumsley.org/jwacs/), but this project to be discontinued. Sadly, Babel (https://babeljs.io/) does not support it :(.

Any help?

Comment: For this to exist on a broad variety of JavaScript implementations, the underlying implementations have to be able to generate a continuation as an artifact.  You can't fake this with a library using existing standard javascript features.  So why would you expect this to exist?

Comment: IMHO, if you use a transpiler (source-to-source compiler), you can do it. So,  you may probably find a library that uses a transpiler to introduce continuations.

Comment: A "transpiler" has to use the target language primitives to implement any concepts it may have.  Explain how it can implement a continuation,  if the target language cannot capture execution state?

Comment: Transforming the code to Continuation-Passing Style(CPS) and you capture the "k" value (function (... k))?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you may be looking for are generators, which are supported by babel:
https://babeljs.io/learn-es2015/#ecmascript-2015-features-generators

Comment: Hi, I think generators do not allow to suspend/stop a computation or exchange a computation with another one. For example, using continuations, you can replace the current computation with an "empty" continuation (ie. a computation), which ends up stopping the execution of the program.